# AS3: Getting a color value from a bitmap

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap

I'm attempting to retrieve a color value when I click an image on the stage. I'm planning to use this to create a height map for a game I'm working on, making the character move slower over rough terrain (portions of the height map with a specific color value), but I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::MovieClip@2fc84f99 to flash.display.Bitmap.
at testGetColor2_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
```

Here's my code so far:

```
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite;

var container:Sprite = new Sprite();

var myHeightMap:Bitmap = Bitmap(heightMap);

this.addChild(container);
container.addChild(myHeightMap);

container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var obj:Sprite = e.currentTarget as Sprite;

    var myHeightMap:Bitmap = Bitmap(obj.getChildAt(0));

    var pixelValue:uint = myHeightMap.bitmapData.getPixel(mouseX,mouseY);

    trace(pixelValue.toString(16));
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you can't just convert a `MovieClip` to a `Bitmap` by casting it like you're trying to do when creating `myHeightMap`. To do that conversion, use the following:

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(heightMap.width, heightMap.height);
bitmapData.draw(heightMap);
var myHeightMap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
```

Of course, there might be other ways to do this. If you could find a way to have `heightMap` as a `Bitmap` before this code is called, that would be more efficient.

Comment: You sir, ROCK!!!! It's working!!! Thanks so much :)
Wish I could upvote but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Glad to help! If your problem is solved, then you should mark whichever answer was most helpful as 'accepted'. :)

Answer (score 0):

The way how you doing it is not quite right :)

This is how you convert the the MovieClip to Bitmap:

```
function toBitmap(value:DisplayObject):Bitmap
{
    var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(value.width, value.height, true, undefined);
    bmpData.draw(value, null, null, null, null, true);

    return new Bitmap(bmpData, "auto", true);
}
```

And then you can get the pixel.

Remember that RegistrationPoint must be TOP_LEFT.